# Drupal commerce and multiple products sharing SKU

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a commerce shop, and a question about product "sharing" SKU.

I have products which is sold as single products, but also in a box.

Lets say I have "Product A" with price $ 1 , with SKU 00001.

I have a box with 10 x "product A" which on the website should appear as "Product A box" and price $ 9. (I need it to be the same product, but shown as separate "product"

I need it because, if I have two separate products, then I can't be sure I have the correct amount in stock.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that with [Commerce Product Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle). Some details about it, from its project page:

> This module extends Drupal Commerce by allowing the site admin to
>   collect a number of existing products together in a bundle, and offer
>   them at a new bundle price, with a new bundle SKU.
>
> You can define products that consists of other products. They are all
>   combined in one add to cart form which works like the core add to cart
>   form. The bundle is then represented by one order line item. This
>   allows the maximum compatibility with other modules such as shipping
>   or payment modules.

As an alternative, there is also [Commerce Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bundle). Some details about it, from its project page:

> Implements product bundles for Drupal Commerce. For example, you want
>   to offer products A, B, and C for a lower cost if purchased together
>   rather than standalone. Notable features include setting the prices at
>   the bundle group or product level, and product attribute support.

**Note**: if you wonder how those to modules compare to each other, then this might help (= quote from the [Commerce Product Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle) project page):

> [Commerce Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bundle) also allows creating product bundles. Customers add a bundle to their cart, but the component products show in checkout and order history. It therefore doesn't allow assigning an overall price to the bundle (but it has some neat ways to assign prices to component products). With Commerce Product Bundle, the bundle, not the component products, show in checkout and order history. Therefore an overall price can be assigned to the bundle